# webstorm 8: trying to exclude bower_components and keep autocompletion

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, bower

I am trying to remove from general search, todo's list bower_components folder, but yet keep autocompletion in place. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest the following:
- in Settings/javascript/libraries, add bower_components folder as a library
- disable it

Does it help?
See also [IDEA-97846](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97846)